# Get UTC Offset in hours from Datetimeindex Pandas Series localtime

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `datetime_index` parameter which is a Datetimeindex series already timezone aware (UTC Timezone) but i need to get a offset value in hours for the Timezone "Europe/Lisbon".

I was using this function:

```
def get_offset(datetime_index):

    local = pytz.timezone('Europe/Lisbon')
    dt = datetime_index
    offset = [local.utcoffset(dt[x], is_dst=True).seconds / 3600 for x in range(dt.__len__())]
    return offset
```

But now that the values came already in UTC is no longer valid.

Later on i changed a little the `offset` variable to this:

```
def get_offset(datetime_index):

    local = pytz.timezone('Europe/Lisbon')
    offset = [datetime_index[x].astimezone(local).utcoffset().seconds/3600 for x in range(len(datetime_index))]
    return offset
```

It seems to be working but i'm a little worried about the consequences of using this in large datasets. Is there any other way? Or this way is fine?

Comment: I have the same/similar "old" question, still unanswered. I use : `timezone_offset_minutes_series = timestamps.map(lambda ts: ts.utcoffset().total_seconds() / 60)` but this is rather slow in the context of massive time series and a function that should perform fast. Is there a way to make this faster ?